# Bot not detecting the embed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

```
    const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

    const client = new Client({
      intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
      ]
    });

    const yourUserID = '';
    const specificBotID = '';
    let cooldown = false;

    client.once('ready', () => {
      console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
    });

    client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
      if (message.author.id === specificBotID) {
        // Check if the message is from the specific bot

        if (!cooldown) {
          // If the bot is not on cooldown, tag and set the cooldown

          console.log('Received message:', message);
      
          // Check if the message has embeds
          if (message.embeds.length > 0) {
            const embed = message.embeds[0];
            const embedColor = embed.hexColor || embed.color;
        
          if (embedColor) {
          // Sending the message with the hex color included
          message.channel.send(`<@${yourUserID}> The specific bot sent a message. The embed color is ${embedColor}.`);
        } else {
          message.channel.send(`<@${yourUserID}> The specific bot sent a message. The embed color is not available.`);
        }
      } else {
        message.channel.send(`<@${yourUserID}> The specific bot sent a message, but no embeds were found.`);
      }
      
      cooldown = true;

      // Set a 2-second cooldown
      setTimeout(() => {
        cooldown = false;
      }, 2000);
        }
      }
    });
```

I am trying to make a discord bot that detects if an embed is sent and sends a message containing the colour Stripe of the embed. But it is not detecting an embed at all as I printed the message info and the embed array was empty. Could anyone take a look and lmk whats wrong

Comment: You might rethink your cooldown logic, because you start the timer whenever messageCreate is called, even if it was already on cooldown. So for instance you call it, it starts 2s cooldown, after 1s someone calls it it starts another cooldown. So now the cooldown flag will be set to false in 1s and 2s, meaning that a call between 1-2s will have only <1s cooldown.

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski I did think of that that's why I set it so it only responds to the specific bot ID for now, at least until I make sure the code is functional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the Message Content intent (and therefore, MessageContent in your intents code) in order to see the embeds or content objects for messages the bot doesn't own. Note that you'll have to [toggle this](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents) in the developer portal.

Comment: Appreciate it brother